# How do I get network render on RPi 4?

Tags: add-on, network

I'm looking to create a render farm at my house from Raspberry Pi 4s, but I'm checking on my 3 and there isn't a network render addon in the menu. Is it possible to bring the feature back somehow or is it dead forever for the raspberry pi?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, I think it's a nice spare time project. However, one threadripper or one good gpu would beat even 50 of them.

Comment: If you want to render an animation (and not a still image), you don't need any addon, only a few options to check/uncheck. Let me now if you want me to elaborate.